# SQL query that search in multiple columns multiple words

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question that I can't find an answer to it.

I want the user to enter words and on every ENTER press I send the word(s) to the server to search

I need my sql to search in 3 tables:

`Products` table:

```
PRODUCT NAME, PRODUCT DESCRIPTION, PRODUCT TAGS
```

`User` table:

```
USERNAME, USER EMAIL
```

`user-info` table:

```
ADDRESS, LANGUAGE
```

Let's say that

```
 $d = array('0'=>'cell phone','1'=>'lightweight','2'=>'brasil','3'=>'nokia');
```

I need that all the SQL will search for everything everywhere

This is the closest I have arrived, I'm looking in only one table and one coll, I have no idea what to do.

```
public function getAllByTags($d){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.TBL_WORKS.' WHERE tags ';
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($d);$i++){
        $sql .= 'LIKE \'%'.$d[$i].'%\'';
        if(sizeof($d) != 1  && $i != sizeof($d)-1 && $i != sizeof($d)){
            $sql .= ' OR ';
        }
    }
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
        $q[] = $row;
    }
    return $q;
}
```

I'm sure there's an answer somewhere in google but my English is not that good (i think :/),

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE %yourstring
```

you can do the search above on multiple columns
and if you want to do it on multiple tables you can run 3 subqueries and use union.
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574564/php-mysql-search-multiple-tables-using-a-keyword)