# Outputting query results on the right place

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have set up the following query based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574564/php-mysql-search-multiple-tables-using-a-keyword) question:

```
"(SELECT users_id, first_name, last_name, 'msg' as type FROM users 
 WHERE users_id LIKE '%" . $searchQuery ."%' 
 OR first_name LIKE '%" . $searchQuery ."%' 
 OR last_name LIKE '%" . $searchQuery ."%') 
 UNION
 (SELECT title, vimeo_id, upload_date, 'topic' as type FROM video 
 WHERE title LIKE '%" . $searchQuery ."%' 
 OR vimeo_id LIKE '%" . $searchQuery ."%')"
```

After the query is executed it should spit out the results like this:

```
foreach($row as $field) {
    $details[] = array(
        // Fields uit de users table
        'user_id'       =>  $field['users_id'],
        'first_name'    =>  $field['first_name'],
        'last_name'     =>  $field['last_name'],
        //Fields uit de video table
        'vimeo_id'      =>  $field['vimeo_id'],
        'video_title'   =>  $field['title'],
        'upload_date'   =>  $field['upload_date']
    );
}
```

It works but I still encounter a problem. When I run the script with a searchterm that should be within the 'user' table there is no problem. When I run the script with a searchterm that should be within the 'video' table I still get results but it moves the results to the first part of the loop. That means I get the following output:

```
[{"user_id":"Test","first_name":"151125560","last_name":"2016-01-08 10:49:32","vimeo_id":null,"video_title":null,"upload_date":null}]
```

While the video id should be `151125560`, the video title should be `test` and the upload_date should be `2016-01-08`.

I tried to solve this by adding `as type` but I have no clue on how to proceed from here. Could somebody please help me by moving the results to the right field?

Comment: For me this query is weird as the 2 select queries don't return the **same** **columns** at this should be done with UNION. Maybe you should try a **JOIN** of the two tables instead to have the informations on the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UNION query:

```
"(SELECT users_id, first_name, last_name, 'msg' as type FROM users 
 WHERE users_id LIKE '%" . $searchQuery ."%' 
 OR first_name LIKE '%" . $searchQuery ."%' 
 OR last_name LIKE '%" . $searchQuery ."%') 
 UNION
 (SELECT title, vimeo_id, upload_date, 'topic' as type FROM video 
 WHERE title LIKE '%" . $searchQuery ."%' 
 OR vimeo_id LIKE '%" . $searchQuery ."%')"
```

is going to spit out four fields (`users_id`,`first_name`, and `last_name` and `type`). It will not spit out a field called `title` or `vimeo_id`, `upload` because those field names are in the second query.

Basically in a UNION we are saying the result sets of the two select statements are the same field-wise. And it always uses the field names specified in the first SELECT statement.

So you should instead do:

```
foreach($row as $field) {
    $details[] = array(
        // Fields uit de users table
        'user_id'       =>  $field['users_id'],
        'first_name'    =>  $field['first_name'],
        'last_name'     =>  $field['last_name'],
     );
}
```

And just expect the results to always be in those fields (since they are).

Instead, you could do something like:

```
foreach($row as $field) {
    if $field['type'] == 'topic'
    {
        $details[] = array(
            // Fields uit de users table
            'user_id'       =>  $field['users_id'],
            'first_name'    =>  $field['first_name'],
            'last_name'     =>  $field['last_name'],
            //Fields uit de video table
            'vimeo_id'      =>  '',
            'video_title'   =>  '',
            'upload_date'   =>  ''
        );

    } else {
        $details[] = array(
            // Fields uit de users table
            'user_id'       =>  '',
            'first_name'    =>  '',
            'last_name'     =>  '',
            //Fields uit de video table
            'vimeo_id'      =>  $field['users_id'],
            'video_title'   =>  $field['first_name'],
            'upload_date'   =>  $field['last_name']
        );
    }

}
```

Forgive me if my php syntax is off. It's been a year or two and I'm rusty.

Comment: unbelievable it was actually that easy.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When in doubt, run your query through phpmyadmin or whatever mysql client you are partial too. Seeing an actual resultset will help out tremendously when dealing with more complex stuff in the DB.

Comment: Well, thats what i did, and that made my figure out how to set up the query. But i didn't know how i could use type like you showed! Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed there still is a small issue. In the else statement you inserted the wrong fields. Could you explain to me why i can only pick up the value with $field['users_id'] instead of $fields['vimeo_id']?

Comment: Because in the result set of your UNION query there are only 4 fields. Those 4 fields are given their name by the first query in the UNION. So you'll find the value for `vimeo_id` that you selected from the `video` table in Result Set's field `users_id`. In essence, a union query for your scenario is somewhat inappropriate, BUT! It's a good solution for your needs, where you want to search two unrelated tables with a single query. Perhaps, for clarity, change your first query to something like `SELECT users_id AS uid_OR_vid, first_name as fn_OR_vidTitle, etc..` so the result set makes sense.

Comment: Just checked it out and works great, isn't union the best way to go for making a search?

Comment: Yea. For your case, it's the best way to go. Otherwise you would have to submit multiple queries and then stumble around with multiple result sets and yuck. It's just confusing because you get this result set object back with natural language field names that don't necessarily represent the data in those fields. But... you ignore the field names (or name them generically) and pray the poor fool that comes on to the team in a year or two is able to figure out whats what. ;)

Comment: Haha, as i probably would been that poor fool that had to figure it out in two years (as this is my project) i invested a little extra effort in getting the fields names right. Thanks again.