# How to search in two different tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, union

Here is my current queries:

```
$q = $request->q;
-- first table
$n_arr = news::where('title','like',$q)->orWhere('description','like',$q)->get();
-- second table
$p_arr = productions::where('title','like',$q)->orWhere('description','like',$q)->get();
```

as you see, currently I do that by two different queries. But now I need to use `->paginate()`, So I need a single query to paging all results as well. I need something like `union` clause.

In other word, I need to combine the result of those two queries above.

How can I do that in Laravel?

Comment: use `UNION` to connect them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574564/php-mysql-search-multiple-tables-using-a-keyword

Comment: Look at JOIN if there is a column that links these 2 tables

Comment: @RiggsFolly No there isn't any common column between them.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to [create pagination manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator).

Another way to do that is to use [`skip()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) and [`take()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) methods in both queries to get results for current page.

```
$n_arr = news::where('title','like',$q)->orWhere('description','like',$q)->->skip($page * $perPage)->take($perPage)get();
$p_arr = productions::where('title','like',$q)->orWhere('description','like',$q)->skip($page * $perPage)->take($perPage)->get();
```

Comment: well still there is two results: both `$n_arr` and `$p_arr` .. Should I use `->render()` on which one?

Comment: Still I'm trying to fix this problem ... I really don't know how should I use paginate on two different queries.

Comment: @stack, you should `render()` only if you're craeting `Paginator` object manually. If you're using `skip()` and `take()`, you should create links manually without `render()`