# How to optimize searching for a value across 2 MySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to determine if a user supplied value exists in 2 different MySQL tables, and which table it exists in.  I know I could do:

```
SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE col_name_table1 = user_value;
```

And if the user value does not exist there, then I could just check the next table:

```
SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE col_name_table2 = user_value;
```

In my PHP logic, which executes the SQL queries above, I can easily capture which table the user value exists in depending on the values returned from the queries (i.e. 0, 1).

I'm wondering though, is there a more elegant way to do what I need?
**Is it possible to write a single query that checks both tables, and then returns the table where the user value is found?**

Comment: use joins for these quesies

Comment: don't store them in two separate tables to begin with. Two tables holding the same content doesn't make sense

Comment: It's not join you need but union.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mysql search multiple tables using a keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574564/php-mysql-search-multiple-tables-using-a-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a UNION ALL would work?

```
(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE col_name_table1 = user_value) UNION ALL (SELECT 2 FROM table2 WHERE col_name_table2 = user_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Running two queries in a single one is possible using `UNION ALL` or `CASE WHEN` or `SUB QUERIES`, but it is not an optimized way. Do this by php only as you know if and else case. If you get a result from the first table it will hardly takes .01 sec, and if not in first then on else condition will .01 sec more. But once you create some `UNION` or SUB it will increase upto **2.0 to 3.0** sec